# How to modify input values in directives with model driven / reactive forms

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I want to implement a "TrimDirective", which deletes leading and trailing spaces from input fields, with Angular 2 RC 5 and model driven / reactive forms.

I managed to change the value of the input field, however I don't get a new value in the component in `myForm.valueChanges()`.

See this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ruzqCh?p=preview

How can I trigger a update of the formGroup when the directive changes the value?

**template**:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <input formControlName="name" trim>
</form>
latest value: -{{ latestValue }}-
```

**component**:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  private myForm: FormGroup;
  private latestValue: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(),
    });
    this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(v => this.latestValue = v.name)
  }
}
```

**directive**:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[trim]'
})

export class TrimDirective {

    private el: any;

    constructor(
        el: ElementRef
    ){
        this.el = el.nativeElement;
    }

    @HostListener('keypress')
    onEvent() {
        setTimeout(() => { // get new input value in next event loop!
            let value: string = this.el.value;
            if(value && (value.startsWith(' ') || value.endsWith(' '))) {
                console.log('trim!');
                this.el.value = value.trim();
            }
        },0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try changing `onEvent` to `onKeyDown`

Comment: @viku  that's not the issue.   the issue is that `this.el.value = value.trim();` updates the input's value and the DOM, but angular's "model" doesn't change.  how can the directive force a `detectChanges()` or emit an event or something/anything (access the component/FormGroup/FormControl ?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create and trigger a change event on the element to tell angular to update the model value.

```
let event: Event = document.createEvent("Event");
event.initEvent('input', true, true);
Object.defineProperty(event, 'target', {value: this.elementRef.nativeElement, enumerable: true});
this.renderer.invokeElementMethod(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'dispatchEvent', [event]);
```

Comment: I moved to template driven model in the meanwhile, but yeah, thanks, that works! http://plnkr.co/edit/CLrA3b5v1V8LgszC3Vqi?p=preview

Comment: note to others:  add `private renderer: Renderer` to directive's constructor params and add `import { Renderer } from '@angular/core';` to the file.    Finally, unrelated:  make sure that you're using the correct `this`  I'm embarrassed to say that I've probably been trying various solutions to this problem inside an event listener callback where the context of this has changed.  d'oh

Comment: the renderer is deprecated in the last version of angular and in the rendered2 it dosen't any invokeElementMethod